# How to plot a "linear" trend line in a plot with log-scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a linear trend line in a plot with logarithmic scale on the y-axis indicating that the underlying data decays exponentially.

Here is my code:

```
data = self.global_objects_per_frame

(n, bins, patches) = plt.hist(data, bins=np.arange(min(data), max(data)+1), alpha=0.5, range=[0, 40])

plt.yscale('log', nonposy='clip')
plt.xlim(0, 40)

plt.title('Pedestrian Density', fontweight='bold')
plt.xlabel('# of pedestrians', fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('# of frames', fontweight='bold')

ax = plt.gca()

ax.yaxis.grid(which="major", color='black', linestyle=':', linewidth=1)

for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis]:
    axis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())

x = bins.tolist()
x = x[:41]

y = n.tolist()
y = y[:41]

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)

p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x, p(x), "r--")

plt.savefig(os.path.join(outputPath, self.name, 'PedestrianDensity'), dpi = 300)
```

The result of this code is the dashed red line, but what I really want is the solid red line.

Can anybody help me to fix my code?

[image]

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: It seems a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180910/plotting-a-trendline-on-a-logarithmic-scale).

Answer (score 1):

You want to fit a line to the logarithmically scaled data, not the data itself. Hence you would need to fit

```
z = np.polyfit(x, np.log10(y), 1)
```

Then you need to scale the fit back to data coordiantes, such that it "appears" as line,

```
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x, 10**p(x), "r--")
```

Comment: this code correction seems right, but now I get "NaN" (not a number) for the two coefficients of the polyfit function

Comment: This can have all kinds of reasons, but how could anyone know. Please read [mcve].